# Create a %union into a list in maxima

Tags: maxima

The function `to_poly_solve` in maxima returns a `%union` but I want to work with a list.

How can `%union`s be turned into lists since `listify` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
abc : %union([a = 2], [b = 3]);
args(abc);
```

Answer (score 2):

This function worked for me:

```
LISTIFY(Union) := block(
                        [res : []],
                        (for si in Union do res : append(res, [si])),
                        return (res)
                       );
```

Usage:

```
abc : %union([a = 2], [b = 3]);
LISTIFY(abc);
```

Output:

```
%union([a=2],[b=3])
[[a=2],[b=3]]
```